# WPF - prevent ListBox item selection

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate

I would like to prevent selection of ListBoxItems in my ListBox. My DataTemplate has a checkbox and this should be the only thing the user can click or select.
How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is almost a duplicate question.  In fact, you're asking two questions here:

1. Either style your `ListBoxItem` so that it doesn't show selection (look elsewhere on SO for that answer), or replace `ListBox` with `ItemsControl` if you don't need the other features that `ListBox` provides.
2. Bind your checkbox's IsChecked property to the parent `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` property:

   ```
   <CheckBox 
      IsChecked="{Binding
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                        AncestorType=ListBoxItem},
         Path=IsSelected}"
   />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When your user will try to (un)check your checkboxes then item become 'active' in some way. And focused style will be applied. As far as i know there is no way to disable selection(because if you did your checkboxes will not work) but you can override focused(or selected) style of your listbox items